# Extra chars in django template

Tags: django

I've some code like this:

```
<select id="form.category}}">
    {% for category in form.category %}
        <option value="{{ category }}"></option>
    {% endfor %}
</select>
```

And result is:

https://zapodaj.net/940329c1516df.png.html

Why?

@edit

```
category = models.CharField(max_length=100, choices=get_categories())

def get_categories():
    categories = (
        ("wydarzenia", "wydarzenia"),
        ("informacje", "informacje"),
        ("konkursy", "konkursy"),
        ("wycieczki", "wycieczki"),
        ("sport", "sport"),)
    return categories
```

form.category is a field in model

Comment: What is `form.category`?

Comment: It's a list of category

Comment: Please show the rendered html (e.g. click 'view source'). Do you really have `id="form.category}}"` - the `}}` without `{{` looks very strange.

Answer (score 1):

The option looks empty because you are not showing anything inside the options tag. You need to display some labels for option tag. Do something like this if category is an object and it has attributes like id and name.

```
<select id="form.category">
    {% for category in form.category %}
        <option value="{{ category.id }}">{{category.name}}</option>
    {% endfor %}
</select>
```

If category is a string or number do something like this

```
<select id="form.category">
    {% for category in form.category %}
        <option value="{{ category }}">{{category}}</option>
    {% endfor %}
</select>
```

Bear in mind that form.category should be an iterable.

Comment: I don't have value option, anything

Comment: What is `form.category` ? Can you post the value here?

Comment: what is `category` ? Is it an object? What are its attributes?

Comment: `<option value="{{ category.0 }}">{{category.1}}</option>` should work then